# Linq XML code not yielding the desired result. Shows no item

Tags: wpf, xml, linq, xaml, linq-to-xml

i have the following code but don't understand where am i getting wrong. There are five items in the xml file but this code shows none.

```
public static List<string> LoadLedgersString()
    {
        List<string> ListLedgerStringRecords = new List<string>();
        // Execute the query using the LINQ to XML
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Ledgers.xml");
        var records = from r in doc.Element("Ledgers").Elements("Ledger") select r;
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            string lLedgerString = record.Element("Name").Value;
            ListLedgerStringRecords.Add(lLedgerString);
        }
        return ListLedgerStringRecords;
    }
```

The code that is calling and utilizing its result is following

```
List<string> ledgerList = new List<string>();
        ledgerList = DAL_Ledgers.LoadLedgersString();

        ledgerListView.DataContext = ledgerList;
        ICollectionView view =
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ledgerList);

        new TextSearchFilter(view, this.searchTextBox);
```

Comment: your code is fine if your xml is something like this `<Ledgers><Ledger><Name>LedName</Name></Ledger></Ledgers>` but if your schema is like `<Ledgers><Ledger Name="LedName"></Ledger>  </Ledgers>` then you need to use `record.Attribute` instead of `record.Element`

Comment: my code is like dat only dats why i am confused, not using any attribute.....i tried uploading the xml code but its not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be a problem with namespacing or with pathing.

Please post some example XML, then we can try to help.